# jQuery Ajax population of dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having problem with the dynamic populations of 3 dropdowns with ajax

```
  $.ajax({
            url:"loadPersons",
            success:function(data) {
                loadPersons(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            }
        });
```

and here is my other ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                    url:"loadCars?personId=8796093056989",
                    data:{"personId":personId},
                    success:function(data) {
                        loadCars(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    }
```

The first one returns all persons, and the second one should return the cars of the person with the specified ID. However, when I press something from the first one, all of the objects come to the second dropdown. Do you have any idea how to do the filtering?

Comment: why are you passing the personId twice?  your specifying the data object which has personId but also adding it to the Url?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using something like

`url:"loadCars?personId="+$('#persons-ddl').val()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your second ajax call to be:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:"loadCars",
    data:
    {
        "personId":personId // this is the id of the selected person in your person combobox
    },       
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
    {
    }
}).done(function(data)
{
   loadCars(data);
});
```